# SML - Errors in code

Tags: syntax-error, sml

I'm making an SML lambda calculus translation function and I have run into several errors and I don't know how to fix it.

```
    cfunf id (CAPP(e1,e2))=
          if not(cfree id (CAPP(e1,e2)))
             then CAPP(CK,CAPP(e1,e2))
             else
             if ((CID id) = e2) andalso not(cfree id e1)
             then e1
             else CAPP(CAPP(CS, (cfunf id e1)),(cfunf id e2));
```

The errors I get are RPAREN THEN and ELSE IDA. I'm pretty sure RPAREN is for an unbalance in parenthesis but there is none I can see. This code is required for the following function. I'm sure it some simple syntax error but I have no idea how too proceed so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It's very helpful to have a text editor that highlights matching parentheses. Most modern editors can be configured to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You added and extra parenthesis. Remove the last `)` from

```
if ((CID id) = e2) andalso not(cfree id e1))
```

So it becomes

```
if ((CID id) = e2) andalso not(cfree id e1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The line with the second `if` has 3 opening but 4 closing parentheses. (In fact only one pair of parens is actually needed there.)